# What would be causing a thick black diagonal line in front of my camera's sensor?

Tags: canon, sensor, equipment-damage, shutter

I have a Canon XTi. On every photo I take I have a thick diagonal black line appear on the photograph. See an example picture:

[image: example of black line]

My next discovery came when I selected `Sensor Cleaning: Manual` in the camera options which makes the mirror move up and out of the way of the sensor. I then took a picture looking at the sensor. There is a thick plastic thing in the way of the sensor. Here is a picture:

[image: picture of thick plastic thing in front of the sensor]

Does anyone know what this plastic thing in front of the sensor is? It is still attached to the camera so I cannot pull it out.

Answer (score 50):

From what I see this is element from the shutter. And my humble advise is to send your camera to repair shop, give it in to the hands of professional, do not try to repair it.

Comment: yep, definitely looks like one of the elements of the shutter curtain has become detached on one side

Answer (score 21):

The item obstructing the sensor is a shutter blade.  Your shutter has failed and needs to be replaced.  There's no hack or DYI solution for this problem.  This is a hardware problem and not something that can be fixed with software or some kind of hack.

You should expect repairs to be in the $200+ price range. Since you can buy a used XTi for under $150, you will most likely end up throwing your camera away at a local e-waste recycling center and buying a replacement.

Comment: There's a contradiction here: if the shutter needs to be replaced, there certainly is a DIY solution in doing exactly that. It's no doubt a very complicated repair that requires a lot of skill and which might not succeed, but it's not impossible. And before throwing it away, why not have a look inside to see what this strange plastic thing actually is? There's nothing to lose at this point and only experience and knowledge to be won. You can still throw it away after taking it apart and understanding how impossible the repair really is.

Comment: The estimate of repair costs seems applicable to western countries. If OP lives in India or China, [his repair costs may be considerably lower.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/111449/18252)

Comment: @null There's no doubt what it is. It is a blade from one of the shutter curtains. As to the other, if one needs to ask here what that is it is highly doubtful they have the knowledge required to be able to successfully replace a shutter assembly themselves, which requires pretty much total disassembly-reassembly of the camera. Good judgment is the result experience. Experience is usually the result of bad judgement. If the OP wants to try it, that's fine. But the result is almost certainly going to be experience, not a working camera.

Comment: Hey guys, it's OP - I'm in Australia, so the repair cost would be more expensive than the camera is worth. I'm willing to experiment and try to replace the shutter assembly (even if I fail, it's no harm). Where would I buy a replacement shutter assembly? I don't know what they look like. Would this one on eBay work? https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Shutter-Assembly-Group-for-Canon-EOS-350D-EOS-400D-Digital-Camera-Repair-Part/251533415144?hash=item3a908f52e8%3Ag%3ASeUAAOxyedRTdtgS&_sacat=0&_nkw=canon+eos+shutter+assembly+400d&_from=R40&rt=nc&_trksid=m570.l1313&LH_TitleDesc=0

Comment: @MichaelClark seeing as the advice is more or less to junk it and get a new one, you might as well open it up. Doesn't sound like there is much to lose.

Comment: Don't throw it away! Sell it on a local craigslist as an item in need of repair. I'm sure someone with experience in these things will want it if that's so easy for them to fix. If you try to fix it yourself, you risk breaking it and reducing potential resale value.

Comment: @IPhotographMaybe Yes, that's the correct assembly.  The 400D is the same camera as the Rebel XTi - the name just depends on what country you bought it in.  If you're going to try to repair just be very careful  - there are tutorials online for this exact job.  Follow closely and be sure to have as clean a workspace as you can find.  Use a duster can gently as you reassemble to keep as much dust out of the body as possible.

Comment: @IPhotographMaybe I suggest you do not buy anything before you haven't taken the camera apart up until the point where the new shutter assembly is actually required. If at that point you feel comfortable getting that mess back together, consider if you want to invest the money for the spare part into a still likely failing attempt to repair the camera. But again, first get a working replacement camera. That's what changes the necessity to fix your broken camera into the possiblitity of repairing it into a backup body.

Comment: @null There is no contradiction at all. Obviously the asker could, _in principle_ learn to do anything that can be done by a professional repairer. Heck, Canon and their suppliers were able to make the camera from stuff that they dug out of the ground -- _in principle_, the asker could do that, too, and just build themself a new camera! However, the amount of time and effort they would have to put in to learn how to make this repair this is massively more than is likely to be worth it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby an interesting perspective. For all we know OP has a day job as a watch repairman and is a volunteer bomb disposal tech. Just replacing a shutter is a dawdle for some. There's certainly a limit though, with CMOS fabs currently running around $3billion, its probably cheaper to buy a camera from the existing manufacturers. So somewhere between building your own litho facility and throwing a camera away every time the battery dies, in the middle sit jobs that are worth doing but maybe not barely cheaper. That might be a question on it's own right

Comment: @PhotoScientist I'm willing to bet that the asker is neither a watch repairman nor a bomb disposal tech. The overwhelming majority of people are not capable of repairing camera shutters without investing unreasonable amounts of time and effort. I'm somewhat mystified that people are arguing about this.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  I don't think the chances of success are particularly high and I hope that's not what everyone is arguing. Consider this: The average gambling losses per capita in Australia are $1200 per year. The selling price for a used rebel xti is under $100. Given that, a few bucks lost on the longshot that he can repair his camera is pretty paltry. Besides, there's learning to be had from taking a camera apart even if it doesn't go back together. I agree that we shouldnt mislead anybody but encouraging people to tinker _and_ setting their expectations low is beneficial, IMO.

Comment: @PhotoScientist Alas I am not a volunteer bomb disposal tech, guys. The extent of my tinkering has been with things like laptops and cars. I have a backup camera I can use in my day to day. Taking everything you've all said into account, I am happy to risk the small resale cost of the broken camera for the experience of learning and small chance I can put it back together properly. I will enjoy following the online tutorials and taking it apart (it's my idea of fun, actually).

Comment: I think the “Not a DIY repair” is like amputating your leg is ‘not a DIY procedure”. Yes, some people can do it themselves,  but those people are few and far between.